# More precision for time_ago_in_words and distance_of_time_in_words in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4, activesupport

Are there any options to make the `time_ago_in_words` or `distance_of_time_in_words` functions more precise in Rails? [Their documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-time_ago_in_words) mentions options but doesn't specify what they are.

If I pass in times for 38 minutes, those functions will output 38 minutes, which is perfect. But if I pass in 89 minutes, I'll get back 'about 1 hour'. That's just too broad for my purposes, I want more granularity or precision.

Answer (score 3):

I've used [dotiw](https://github.com/radar/dotiw) in this situation. It expands on the Rails version to provide you more control over the output.